# gradle: switching to implementation/testImplementation causing errors when accessing configuration

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project which was building fine when I was using the depricated `compile` and `testCompile`, but when I switch it to `implementation` and `testImplementation`, this reference breaks.

`def jmockit = configurations.testCompile.files.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath`

It gives the error `Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object`

When I try to change it like so

`def jmockit = configurations.testImplementation.files.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath`

I get the error

`Resolving configuration 'testImplementation' directly is not allowed`

Based on other related questions, I've tried

`def jmockit = configurations.compileClasspath.files.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath`

which again gives the `Cannot get property 'absolutePath' on null object` error.

What configuration are testImplementation dependencies going into? How do I access them in this way?

not sure if it's relevant but this is a java project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It breaks because `testCompile` does not extend from `testImplementation`. In fact it's the other way around.

You can see the full test configuration hierarchy in *Figure 3. Java plugin - test source set dependency configurations* from
[Dependency configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) docs.

You must use the `testCompileClasspath` to retrieve the `absolutePath` you seek. Full example below ([Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)):

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "io.mateo.test"

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11")
    testImplementation("org.jmockit:jmockit:1.49")
}

val jmockit = configurations.testCompileClasspath.get().files.filter { it.name.contains("jmockit") }[0]

println(jmockit.absoluteFile)
```

With the above, you will see the path you're after:

```
$ ./gradlew assemble

> Configure project :
C:\Users\fmate\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jmockit\jmockit\1.49\e281fc6778c43060402505f062f6515c2adeb037\jmockit-1.49.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 731ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
```